# How do I create a database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a database in my visual studio project, but each time I try and error message pops up; here is the error message i get in my visual studio:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 – Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.)

What should I do?

Comment: your credential are wrong

Answer (score 1):

Often when SQL Server is installed, you can not connect to it using TCP IP. 
You will have to enable it.

Here is a link how to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017